# Get overall covid-19 cases using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, request

I want to add a covid-19 overall cases counter in Russia on my website. To do that, i make a request from https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/russia using the following code

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
let a = httpGet('https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/russia')
console.log(a)
```

And I need to get the confirmed cases from the last element. Can somebody help, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you edit your question to say why your current approach isn't working?

Comment: when I do `console.log(a[a.length - 1].Confirmed)` it returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is string in your example.
Try this to parse it to json array first:

```
b = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(b[b.length - 1])
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jb23hn6s/